# Haskell: print TextEncoding

Tags: haskell, localization, locale, ghc

Haskell newbie here.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
```

While trying to debug weird locale-related bug in third-party Haskell program, I'm trying to print default encoding:

```
import System.IO
main = do
  print localeEncoding
```

But it fails:

```
$ ghc -o printlocale main.hs
main.hs:4:2:
    No instance for (Show TextEncoding)
      arising from a use of `print' at main.hs:4:2-21
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show TextEncoding)
    In the expression: print localeEncoding
    In the expression: do { print localeEncoding }
    In the definition of `main': main = do { print localeEncoding }
```

My google-fu is failing me. What am I missing?

Comment: GHC 7.0 and later have a `Show TextEncoding` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print a value of some type in Haskell, the type must be an instance of the Show class.

```
localeEncoding :: TextEncoding
```

and TextEncoding is not an instance of Show.

The TextEncoding type is actually an existential type storing the methods for encoding and decoding:

```
data TextEncoding
  = forall dstate estate . TextEncoding  {
    mkTextDecoder :: IO (TextDecoder dstate),
    mkTextEncoder :: IO (TextEncoder estate)
  }
```

Since these are functions, there's no sensible way to show them. The current localeEncoding is determined using iconv, via the C function  nl_langinfo.

So, TextEncoding as such is not a showable type, so you cannot print it. However, you can construct new values of this type, via mkTextEncoding. E.g. to create a utf8 environment:

```
mkTextEncoding "UTF-8"
```

We might consider a feature request to store the representation of the locale with the TextEncoding, so this label could be printed. However, that's currently not possible.

Comment: So, I have no way at all to print it? How should I debug then?

Comment: What are you trying to debug? Printing the TextEncoding data type won't tell you anything interesting.

Are you trying to find out your current locale?

Comment: The program I was debugging loses correct locale somewhere underway (it is on Haskell and spawns another Haskell-written program), and throws an exception that it is trying to read a wrong byte from input.

Comment: I've worked around this by upgrading to the new version of program that treats all input as UTF-8.