# Can a TextEncoding be converted to a String?

Tags: text, unicode, haskell, locale

It is possible to convert a string to a TextEncoding using

```
mkTextEncoding :: String -> IO TextEncoding
```

Is there any way to do do the reverse? Or, given a TextEncoding, any way to find out any information about that encoding?  There doesn't even seem to be an Eq instance for TextEncoding to allow comparing against the defined encodings in System.IO.

Am I missing something, or is there a technical reason why this should not be possible?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326506/haskell-print-textencoding/3326676#3326676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextEncoding` will be a member of the `Show` class in GHC 7.0.1.  See [ticket #4273](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4273).